# Flask Limiter error: TypeError: Limiter.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'key_func'

Tags: python, flask, rate-limiting

I am attempting to use Flask's rate limiting library to rate limit an API based on the seconds.

So I have used this exact same format to limit requests to an API on an Apache Server. However I am now using an NGINX. I do not thinks this makes a difference but when I run this code:

```
import api

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

limiter = Limiter(app, default_limits=["5/second"], key_func=lambda: get_remote_address)

limiter.limit("5/second", key_func=lambda: request.args.get('token') if 'token' in request.args else get_remote_address)(api.bp)

app.register_blueprint(api.bp)
```

Again I have ran this exact same code on another server, but now it is giving this error:

> limiter = Limiter(app, "5/second", key_func=lambda:
> request.args.get('token') if 'token' in request.args else get_remote_address)
>
> TypeError: Limiter.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'key_func'

Any help would be great. I am using Flask-Limiter in python and running gevent on gunicorn server for NGINX.

Comment: According to https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_limiter.Limiter, only the `key_func` parameter can be passed as a positional argument; all others are keyword-only parameters.

Comment: Perhaps this is a change from an older version of `flask-limiter` used on the other server?

Comment: @chepner You would have thought I would have check the version. Yes I was using an old version, key_func should not have been declared in the Limiter() creation. Thank you, you have help me greatly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Limiter class instantiation is incorrect. Below is the correct one-

`limiter = Limiter(get_remote_address, app=app, default_limits=["200 per day", "50 per hour"])`

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, since app is also a parameter of the **init**() function, app will be interpreted as the value of key_func, and then you pass the value of the second key_func parameter through key_func=get_remote_address, resulting in **init**() The function received more than one value for the key_func parameter, thus throwing an error.

The following is the definition of limiter：

```
 def __init__(
    self,
    key_func: Callable[[], str],
    *,
    app: Optional[flask.Flask] = None,
    default_limits: Optional[List[Union[str, Callable[[], str]]]] = None,
    default_limits_per_method: Optional[bool] = None,
    default_limits_exempt_when: Optional[Callable[[], bool]] = None,
    default_limits_deduct_when: Optional[...
```

Comment: While your answer points to the correct way to fix the issue, it could be improved by adding the actual code that the user should have used for it to work.